# Why json serializer is not compliant with polymorphism?

Tags: c#, oop, windows-8, polymorphism, .net-4.5

I use stock JSON serialiser in .NET 4.5 windows store app -

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
```

I have a class which is supplied by the API provider say

```
class A { public DateTime Date {get;set} }
```

I wanted to hide Date field by doing this (NOTE - **new** keyword):

```
class AEx : A { public new string Date {get;set} }
```

But I am getting exception:

> type 'AEx' is not serializable with DataContractJsonSerializer because the data member 'Date' is duplicated in its type hierarchy.

I understand what it does.. My question however is **not HOW** does it do **but why?**

Logically speaking it should be compatible with the programming features like polymorphism. **Why this class was made to ignore it?**

Comment: something unclear, do you mean AEx is derived from A?

Comment: yep.. sorry missed that. thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your class basically contains two properties with the same name. So if you try to *deserialize* some JSON which contains that property name, there's no way of knowing which property to set.

Likewise when *serializing* an object of that type, you've got two values which need to be serialized using the same property name - what would you *expect* the JSON to look like?

Fundamentally, a type with two properties of the same name is incompatible with serialization of a plain name/value pair format. (A more advanced serialization mechanism which could specify which property was associated with which declaring class would cope, but JSON doesn't do that.)