# Handling Polymorphism With The DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, json, polymorphism, datacontractserializer

Similar to the situation in [Why json serializer is not compliant with polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705158/why-json-serializer-is-not-compliant-with-polymorphism),

I have a child class inheriting from a base class that overwrites an inherited property using 
the new keyword.

Example Error thrown:

The data contract type 'AEx' is not serializable with DataContractJsonSerializer because the data member 'Date' is duplicated in its type hierarchy.

I know the reason *why* this is not able to de/serialize.

I'd like to understand an approach on how to solve this problem, as at the time, I'm not able to refactor that piece of code specifically.

```
[DataContract]
class A { 
    [DataMember]
    [I'm an attribute]
    public DateTime Date {get;set;} 
}
```

Codebase contains a child class that wanted to overwrite an existing inherited property in order to impose its own set of attributes on it.

```
[DataContract]
class AEx : A { 
    [DataMember]
    [I'm a different attribute]
    new public DateTime Date {get;set;} 
}
```

I'd like to be able to de/serialize this class freely to fro json.

Comment: Use json.net.  you can configure it to serialize type information as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could make Date in class A virtual:

```
[DataContract]
class A 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    [SomeAttribute]
    public virtual DateTime Date {get; set;} 
}
```

and override it in class B:

```
[DataContract]
class B : A 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    [SomeOtherAttribute]
    public override DateTime Date {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: I can't change the existing classes, that ship has sailed. =(

Comment: I see. I tought, you are just not allowed to change the structure of the class. In that case, I am afriad you will have to switch to some alternative .NET Json serializer, since DataContractJsonSerializer is pretty strict about this.